# looking to see @shadream on Twitter. It is a suspended account. It was my account

Tags: twitter

I want to see and save my old twitter account. All of it. Can you help me with that? @Shadream was the name of the account. A suspended account.

Answer (score 1):

While your account is suspended, the only way to retrieve information from it is to request that information from Twitter. You can do that here:

https://help.twitter.com/en/forms/privacy/request-account-info/me

If you think your account was suspended in error, you can see how to request to have it unsuspended here:

https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/suspended-twitter-accounts#how-to-unsuspend-Twitter-account